# Load Lua file and catch any syntax errors

Tags: lua

Is there a function in Lua that will try to load another Lua file and catch any syntax errors? I cannot find anything that doesn't only catch exceptions. Is the solution to include a Lua parser in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loadfile`, like `load`/`loadstring`, returns `nil` plus the error message when there are syntactic errors:

> [Source](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-load): If there are no syntactic errors, returns the compiled chunk as a function; otherwise, returns nil plus the error message.

```
local success, syntaxError = loadfile("myfile.lua")
if not success then
    print("There was a syntax error:", syntaxError)
else
    print("No syntax error")
end
```

A `pcall` is not necessary, since `loadstring` does not throw errors.

Comment: Oh, really? love2d's `love.filesystem.load` will throw an error if there is a syntax error. I will have to bring that up on the forums.

Answer (score 1):

I'm dumb, the answer is obvious:

```
pcall(function()
    loadfile("path/to/file")
end)
```

**Edit:** As pointed out by [Egor Skriptunoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1847592/egor-skriptunoff) in the comments, a more efficient solution:

```
pcall(loadfile, "path/to/file")
```

This works because all arguments after the first argument to `pcall` are passed as arguments to the first argument passed to `pcall`—in this case, `loadfile`.

Comment: Or `pcall(loadfile, "path/to/file")`